# How can I write message from server to an IP/Port using Netty 3.8 ServerBootstrap (TCP)

Tags: tcp, apache-camel, netty, send

I want to send a message from server to an IP/Port but it's not working when I write the channel. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
    private Channel channel;
    private void createConnection() {

    ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));
    this.bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {

        @Override
        public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
            return Channels.pipeline(new SimpleChannelHandler());
        }
    });
    bootstrap.setOption("localAddress", new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 0));
    bootstrap.setOption("reuseAddress", true);
    bootstrap.setOption("child.sendBufferSize", 65536);
    bootstrap.setOption("child.receiveBufferSize", 65536);
    bootstrap.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true);
    bootstrap.setOption("child.keepAlive", true);

    this.channel = bootstrap.bind();
}
```

I'm writing a component using apache camel. When my component proccess, I want it sends a message to an IP/Port.

```
    public void send(Exchange exchange) {

    String ip = exchange.getIn().getHeader("ip", String.class);
    int port = exchange.getIn().getHeader("port", Integer.class);

    Object msg = exchange.getIn().getBody();
    InetSocketAddress inetSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(ip, port);

    this.channel.write(msg, inetSocketAddress);
}
```

I'm getting a "getUnsupportedOperationFuture". I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm using Netty 3.8 and I think the connection is set correctly. Any help?

Comment: Hi! Are you writing a camel component from the scratch? Why not use Apache Camel Netty4 directly? http://camel.apache.org/netty4.html